# How do you get the attachments' urls and post them in console discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a bot in discord.js and I am a bit new to javascript so all this is a little bit hard for me. I have tried to figure out many times how to do this but I can't seem to figure it out, I can't even seem to figure it out from watching tutorials /:

Here is my code:

```js
module.exports = async message => {
    if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
        console.log(`Attachment sent by ${message.author.tag} >> Url: ${Attachment.url}`)
    } else {
        console.log(`\nCHATLOGS - [${message.guild}] ${message.author.tag}: ${message.content}`);
    }
};
```

I am also getting this error: "ReferenceError: Attachment is not defined" and is occurring at line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declarate attachment.It`s a collection, so you need map her to get value.

```js
module.exports = async message => {
    if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
        message.attachments.forEach(Attachment => {
            console.log(`Attachment sent by ${message.author.tag} >> Url: ${Attachment.url}`)
        })
    } else {
        console.log(`\nCHATLOGS - [${message.guild}] ${message.author.tag}: ${message.content}`);
    }
};
```